# React gh-page return 404 errors for certain content (repo in details)

Tags: reactjs, react-router, github-pages

## Problem

---

Forked a react page repository and tried to upload it to github page. After modifying the homepage in `package.json` , the site kind of shows up, but only some components of it. [current state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sUDa.png)

Apologize in advance for missing informations, I will try to provide everything I know as soon as possible.

[Here's my repo](https://github.com/creaper9487/dev-portfolio)

[And here's the original one](https://github.com/mayankagarwal09/dev-portfolio)

[Lastly, the github page](https://creaper9487.github.io/dev-portfolio/)

---

### What has been done / tried

I have tried following things now:

- tried it on local and it works on my machine
- modify the router e.g. https://creaper9487.github.io/reponame/content
- read the log mentioned above
- modify the homepage from `https://creaper9487.github.io/dev-portfolio` to `./` (comment advice form Konrad), then browser return this

```
lockdown-run.js:17 Lockdown failed: TypeError: At intrinsics.Object.groupBy expected boolean not function
  at isAllowedPropertyValue (lockdown-install.js:1:53384)
  at isAllowedProperty (lockdown-install.js:1:53807)
  at visitProperties (lockdown-install.js:1:55095)
  at isAllowedPropertyValue (lockdown-install.js:1:53041)
  at isAllowedProperty (lockdown-install.js:1:53807)
  at visitProperties (lockdown-install.js:1:55095)
  at lockdown-install.js:1:55523
  at repairIntrinsics (lockdown-install.js:1:144597)
  at lockdown-install.js:1:145462
  at lockdown-run.js:4:3
```

```
Protecting intrinsics failed: ReferenceError: harden is not defined
  at lockdown-more.js:69:13
  at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
  at protectIntrinsics (lockdown-more.js:44:22)
  at lockdown-more.js:97:5
```

```
GET https://creaper9487.github.io/profile/home.json 404 (Not Found)
(anonymous) @ Home.jsx:28
Vl @ react-dom.production.min.js:262
t.unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.production.min.js:18
$i @ react-dom.production.min.js:122
Il @ react-dom.production.min.js:261
(anonymous) @ react-dom.production.min.js:261
R @ scheduler.production.min.js:16
x.port1.onmessage @ scheduler.production.min.js:12
```

I speculate that the problem is that gh-pages doesn't work with current route methods, so it tried to access something that is not in the gh-page version of the site. Is there a way to change them to meet how gh-page work, or I need to turn to other ways to deploy it on github?

Comment: Add `"homepage": "./"` to your `package.json`

Comment: I modified the line, it seems to start recognizing the pages, but still can't function well